# how to create a sql express edition installer class

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005

I am creating a winforms application.I want to create a installer program for installing sql express edition in the client computers if sql server is not installed.

How to create installer class to install sql express in the system.and i want to merge the installer program in setup project.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft only supports deploying SQL Server Express by use of their setup.

The only good way to bundle this with your own installer is to bootstrap it (or run their installer from yours).  Luckily there are options built-in for this in Visual Studio.

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

in general, you can send parameters to MSI files. as SQL Express setup file is a MSI file, so you dont need to do it seprately. just in ur setup project execute the setup file and use some parameters to set server name (if u want) and the other things that maybe you need... [here are parameters description you can use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee942965%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)